# How do you add the toolbar back to the viewer after you enterEditMode()?

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

So, my current problem is that when I enter edit mode with MarkupsCore, the toolbar disappears. I have tried numerous ways of adding it back. My latest attempt was this:

```
 var button1 = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button('toolbar-markup');
  button1.setToolTip('Markup');
  button1.addClass('markuptool');
  var toolbar = viewer.toolbar;
  button1.onClick = function(){
      var markups = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore');
      markups.enterEditMode();
      var text = new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.EditModeText(markups);
      markups.changeEditMode(text);
      markups.allowNavigation(true);
      viewer.toolbar = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ToolBar('toolbar');
      viewer.toolbar.addControl(toolbar._controls[0]);
      console.log(toolbar);
  };
```

However, this does not provide me with any errors, and it does not create a UI. I have also tried checking if the toolbar is visible after edit mode is entered, and also if it is collapsed, both of which said, it's visible and not collapsed.

At this point, I am wondering, how do you add the toolbar back to the viewer?

Comment: This is as-designed, when you enter markup edit mode, you are supposed to add or edit markups, so I am wondering what's your goal...

Comment: I want to be able to turn on and off layers while making markups. Would this be at all possible? P.S. Thank you for your blog posts! They have been really helpful.

Comment: You could create your own UI on top of the viewer container which would allow to toggle layers. However I need to check if there is an easier way that lets you display existing toolbar buttons to avoid doing some rework like in this case.

Comment: @SamCurry, Did you find any solution?